# TAB button in HTML Form

Tags: php, javascript, forms

http://www.mastersfunds.com.php5-23.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com/how-to-invest

As seen in that form when I put my cursor in the FIRST NAME field and press TAB on my keyboard, the cursor goes to the right column dropdown instead of LAST NAME

How can I specify the order of the fields when a user uses the TAB button on my keyboard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

specify tabindex in the input

eg

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Controlling TAB Order</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    Field 1 (first tab selection):
    <input type="text" name="field1" tabindex="1" /><br />
    Field 2 (third tab selection):
    <input type="text" name="field2" tabindex="3" /><br />
    Field 3 (second tab selection):
    <input type="text" name="field3" tabindex="2" /><br />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: agree with comment, added quotes.

Comment: While I don't believe you *have* to quote attribute values (unless there's a space between the contained values), it's usually safer/easier/more reliable to always do so. ***Unless*** you need to trim *every* last spare byte from your page...