# use of tab in table td tag

Tags: html

I have the following code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" value="" /></td>
    <td>Middle Name:<input type="text" name="mname" value="" /></td>
    <td>Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Father Name:<input type="text" name="faname" value="" /></td>
    <td>Contact Number:<input type="text" name="num" value="" /></td>
    <td>PIN:<input type="text" name="pin" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and i have focus in First Name input field and i want to shift to Father Name input filed when keyboard tab pressed. Is it possible?

If possible, how code should change.

Comment: check index property for input fields.

Comment: You need `tabindex` http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455865/how-to-change-input-field-switch-sequence-swithcing-input-field-using-tab-key

Comment: possible duplicate of [TAB button in HTML Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236946/tab-button-in-html-form)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the tabindex html attribute:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td >First Name:<input tabindex="1" type="text" name="fname" value="" /></td>
    <td>Middle Name:<input type="text" name="mname" value="" /></td>
    <td>Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Father Name:<input tabindex="2" type="text" name="faname" value="" /></td>
    <td>Contact Number:<input type="text" name="num" value="" /></td>
    <td>PIN:<input type="text" name="pin" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/cKa6t/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [tabindex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_tabindex.asp) property to achieve this.

However, I would think twice about adding a tabindex order to a page that might confuse the user.

Comment: Yes, make sure that there is some logical order. In this case I think the OP wants to handle all of the table's first column first, then the second column etc. That would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
 <tr>
<td>First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" value="" tabindex="1" /></td>
<td>Middle Name:<input type="text" name="mname" value="" /></td>
<td>Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname" value=""  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Father Name:<input type="text" name="faname" value="" tabindex="2" /></td>
<td>Contact Number:<input type="text" name="num" value=""  /></td>
<td>PIN:<input type="text" name="pin" value=""  /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `tabindex`:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name:<input tabindex="1" type="text" name="fname" value="" /></td>
    <td>Middle Name:<input tabindex="3" type="text" name="mname" value="" /></td>
    <td>Last Name:<input tabindex="4" type="text" name="lname" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Father Name:<input tabindex="2" type="text" name="faname" value="" /></td>
    <td>Contact Number:<input tabindex="5"  type="text" name="num" value="" /></td>
    <td>PIN:<input tabindex="6" type="text" name="pin" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But that's probably going to be confusing...